# Navbar code isn't working

Tags: html, css, navbar

Today, I was trying to make a simple css navbar and you know, nothing is working, I'm just stucked! No code is working, even padding is not working.
Any Help?

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gxYdPx << demo

Additionally My code,

style.css

```css
    body {
     margin: 0;
    }
    .navigation {
     background-color: #ecf0f1;
     width: 100%;
     height: 90px;
    }
    .navigation ul {
     overflow: hidden;
     list-style-type: none;
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
    }
    
    .navigation li {
     float: right;
    }
    
    .navigation li a {
     display: block;
        color: white;
        text-align: center;
    
    
        text-decoration: none;
    }
```

```html
index.html

<html>
 <head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
  <title>ZadxHost - The Best You Can Imagine!</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <!-- Navigation Bar -->
  <div class="navigation">
   <h1>ZadxHost</h1>

   <ul>
    <a href="#"><li>Home</li></a>
    <a href="#"><li>Panel</li></a>
    <a href="#"><li>Pricing</li></a>
    <a href="#"><li>Contact Us</li></a>
   </ul>
  </div>

 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You are using wrong structure Inside ul you need to have list items not anchors so the right way is `ul>li>a`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put the `a` elements inside the `li` elements, not the other way around.

So...

```
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        //.....
    </ul>
```

At the moment your CSS is targeting `.navigation li a` which won't work with your current structure.